# How to check used AWS SDK version supported by a region or not?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

How can I know programmatically that used AWS SDK version is compatible with any of the AWS region?

For eg. I am using the ***aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity version 1.11.967*** and if I want to check that given version supported in eu-west-1 region or not. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you are using an OLD Java API. Amazon strongly recommends moving away from Java V1 to AWS SDK for Java V2.

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

**Tip**: You can tell if you are using V2 as the package name always start with **software.amazon.awssdk.services**.

If you are not sure how to work with Amazon Java V2, see this doc topic:

[Get started with the AWS SDK for Java 2.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html)x

To see the latest V2 examples, refer to Github as opposed to Service Guides as they are being updated to get V2 into them.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2

TO answer your question about regions, there is no API that will return this information. The best thing to do is code and test your AWS app using various regions you want to use.

For example, in this **Java V2 DynamoDB** example, notice we are using **US_EAST_1** to create the Service Client. If you are using another region for DynamoDB, replace this region with your region.

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.putitem.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbSortKey;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbBean;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.mapper.annotations.DynamoDbPartitionKey;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.putitem.import]

/*
 * Prior to running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with a key named id and populate it with data.
 * Also, ensure that you have setup your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */
public class EnhancedPutItem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
                .build();

        putRecord(enhancedClient) ;
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.putitem.main]
    // Puts an item into a DynamoDB table
    public static void putRecord(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {

        try {
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> custTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));

            // Create an Instant
            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2020-04-07");
            LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atStartOfDay();
            Instant instant = localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

            // Populate the Table
            Customer custRecord = new Customer();
            custRecord.setCustName("Susan Blue");
            custRecord.setId("id103");
            custRecord.setEmail("sblue@noserver.com");
            custRecord.setRegistrationDate(instant) ;

            // Put the customer data into a DynamoDB table
            custTable.putItem(custRecord);

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }


    @DynamoDbBean
    public static class Customer {

        private String id;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private Instant regDate;

        @DynamoDbPartitionKey
        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        };

        public void setId(String id) {

            this.id = id;
        }

        @DynamoDbSortKey
        public String getCustName() {
            return this.name;

        }

        public void setCustName(String name) {

            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return this.email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {

            this.email = email;
        }

        public Instant getRegistrationDate() {
            return regDate;
        }
        public void setRegistrationDate(Instant registrationDate) {

            this.regDate = registrationDate;
        }
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.putitem.main]
}
```

Comment: Let say AWS service X supports in region A but not in region B in that case, how does it work?